# Find current time interval in python?

Tags: python, time, date-arithmetic

How can I find the nearest 15 (or 10) minute interval in python ?
e.g.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 22, 15, 43, 18, 424873)
```

I'd like the current 15 minute interval (15:30-15:44) so I'd like to transform the above datetime to a

```
datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 22, 15, 30, 00, 00)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite the easiest way to me:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
now = now - timedelta(minutes = now.minute % 15, seconds = now.second, microseconds = now.microsecond )
```

Hope that'll help.

Answer (score 2):

I think for this case using [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.replace) is more straightforward than [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.replace(minute=(now.minute - (now.minute % 15)), second=0, microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 23, 11, 15)
>>>
```

Comment: also need to replace minutes & seconds to zero

Comment: @cfl: You meant seconds & microseconds.  Thanks, I've edited the example.

Answer (score 0):

Look at timedelta()

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/datetime-timedelta.html

Answer (score 0):

Just set minutes on

```
min = min - min %  15
```

and set shorter time units (seconds, msec, ..) on 0